# Enable access for assistive devices programmatically

Tags: macos, cocoa, accessibility, accessibility-api

I want to enable access for assistive devices programmatically.

Have another way to do this that not use

```
NSURL *prefPaneURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"UniversalAccessPref.prefPane"]];
            [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:prefPaneURL];
```

to open System Preferences?

Answer (score 0):

you can use apple script

```
tell application "System Events" to if not UI elements enabled then
    set UI elements enabled to true
end if
```